# Django3 - manage.py commands stuck

Tags: python, django, windows, command-prompt, manage.py

I have a big problem wih Django3: basically, whenever I type a command for manage.py, the prompt gets stuck and never carries on the command without even crashing.

I tried several times the commands "runserver" and "startapp" and waited beetween 10 minutes and an hour, but I never managed to run the server or create an app because I launch the command and the prompt gets stuck.

Strangely enough, to test things out, I created a project, an app and run the server immediately after I installed Django3 and everything worked fine, I even have that project on github. Then I shut down the computer and now nothing works, except my test project.

Also, I noticed in the Windows resource monitor that whenever I try to lauch a command suddenly Python processes start to appear and disappear uncontrollably, and since I never had an issue like this I'm absolutely clueless about everything. So... What's happening? Did someone have the same problem?

I have the lastest Windows update, the latest Python3 (I got it via Windows Store) and the Latest Django3 (I got it via pip). I'd include a stacktrace or some sort of log but, since nothing crashes, I suppose no log gets done: if I'm wrong please correct me, please!

EDIT: I tried uninstalling and installing Python but the problem is the same: I created a test project and I successfully ran the server and started a new app. Once again, I shut down the computer and now everything is broken again.

Comment: can you run python without any errors ?

Comment: yes, absolutely: I tried running it in the command prompt, via PyCharm and via Git Bash and everything looks good

Comment: try `python -m django --version`

Comment: @ansuman this too looks good, I get my version, 3.0.5

Comment: can your run this: `django-admin startproject mysite` this will create a new project mysite.

Comment: Yeah I can create new projects fine, it correctly creates manage.py and everything else

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212571/discussion-between-ansuman-and-alemootasa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks to [ansuman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1720737/ansuman) I discovered virtual environments and now everything works again.

If you're a noob like me and you want to know more go check the [virtual environments documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html), it's extremely helpufl if you're experiencing (supposed) module conflicts like me. Also, it's such a cool feature: start using venv now, you won't regret it.

Here's what I did step-by-step:

- opened the command prompt (duh);
- installed `venv` via `pip`;
- created a folder for the virtual environment with `python -m venv site-venv`;
- went into the newly created directory;
- created a new Django project with `django-admin startproject site`;
- went into the subdirectory Scripts of site-venv and typed `activate`;
- with the virtual environment activated, installed Django via `pip`;
- started doing all the `manage.py` stuff.

Hope this help someone! Thanks again to [ansuman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1720737/ansuman).